# Add field to Shipping Address in Checkout

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, shipping-address

I need to add a field to the checkout process for my store. I have created a field on the frontend where a user can type in the 'Mail Hub' for their location.

How do I capture this information in the backend?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=checkout+fields&pl=0

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an attribute to the customer address eav model in your setup scripts. Something like this:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'field', array(
    'label'     => 'Field',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => true,
    'position'  => 1,
    ));
```

and capture an event in your module's observer. You can use this event for example: checkout_type_onepage_save_order

Then in your observer method

```
public function observerMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $address = $observer->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $address->set{yourFieldName}(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('{yourFieldName}'))->save();
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Will this also create a field in the order object? I will need a field in the order xml called <mail_hub> which captures the customers mail hub info.

Comment: no, order has flat structue, it's in one table. You can add a column to order table in your setup file like this: $connection->addColumn($this->getTable('sales/order'),’field’, “VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL"); And in the observer - add this field from request to your order and save it. Same as with the address